# anchor-spl library 0.25.0 breaks on build

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, anchor-spl

Something seems to be wrong with the [anchor-spl crate (v0.25.0)](https://crates.io/crates/anchor-spl). When I add the following dependencies to my anchor project it breaks the build:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.25.0"
anchor-spl = "0.25.0"

[dev-dependencies]
solana-program-test = "=1.10.38"
```

Throwing the following error:

```
error: failed to select a version for `spl-associated-token-account`.
    ... required by package `anchor-spl v0.25.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `anchor-spl = "^0.25.0"` of package `my_project v0.1.0 (/Users/my_local/my_project/programs/sol_games)`
versions that meet the requirements `~1.0.3` are: 1.0.5, 1.0.3

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `spl-associated-token-account v1.1.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `spl-associated-token-account = "=1.1.1"` of package `solana-transaction-status v1.10.38`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-transaction-status = "=1.10.38"` of package `solana-client v1.10.38`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-client = "=1.10.38"` of package `solana-banks-server v1.10.38`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-banks-server = "=1.10.38"` of package `solana-program-test v1.10.38`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-program-test = "=1.10.38"` of package `my_project v0.1.0 (/Users/my_local/my_project/programs/sol_games)`

failed to select a version for `spl-associated-token-account` which could resolve this conflict
```

I have tried adding `spl-associated-token-account = "1.0.5"` to the dependencies but it also break the build. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build error tells you that `solana-program-test = "=1.10.38"` requires `spl-associated-token-account 1.1.1`, but anchor requires 1.0.5, so you'll have to drop `solana-program-test` to a lower version that also requires 1.0.5.  If you want to be lazy you can do:

```
[dev-dependencies]
solana-program-test = "1.10"
```

And let cargo figure it out. And if that doesn't work, try "1.9".